# How to insert zeros every x bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I represent a square of 1s and 0s with an integer type variable. Here's what it might look like:

```
1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

The corresponding integer is coded from the bottom right corner to the top left, and the top left corner corresponds to 2^0. An integer representation of this grid is: 0000 0000 0010 0111 (2) = 39(10)

The grid is always a square with known width. In my code, I need to increment the width by 1 a lot of times, thus changing the map to:

```
1 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Which is equivalent to inserting a 0 every x = width bits (width = 4 in the example). Overflows can't happen because the size of the integer is much larger than required.

In C, how can I insert a zero every x bits?

Edit1: since this operation will be happening a lot of times on numerous grids, loops are to be avoided.

Edit2: the reason I use this packing is because I do bitwise operations between grids to search for combinations.

Comment: You don't, at least not in a way that is both standard and easy/fast. Which do you prefer?

Comment: "The grid is always a square" - The second example isn't

Comment: How many times exactly do you have to do this?

Comment: What about changing your data representation?  If you often have to increment the width, you may be better off packing down the columns instead of across the rows, or diagonally (a la JPEG DCT order).  Try to find a representation that makes frequent operations fast, even if infrequent operations are slower as a result.

Comment: @Someone: Depends on the input. I'd say "a lot"

Comment: Why don't you just store the original square assuming rows of the max possible length rather than packing.  E.g. if it's a 64-bit int, assume the rows are each 8 bits. Then "growing the square" takes precisely zero instructions, provided you initialize all bits to zero.

Comment: If you allow `_pdep_u32` it's not so bad, then you only need to look up as mask for the width.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the problem in the way you would look as adding 0 to every forth position in decimal number. What you would do in decimal is:

```
1 513 650 -> 105 130 650
```

You can see, that your are just preserving the numbers less than 10^3 and multiplying the rest by 10. Than preserving the number less than 10^7 (not 10^6, because you already multiplied) and multypling the right side by 10....

It works same way for binary.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>

    int power(int x, int n){
        return n == 1 ?  x :  x*power(x,n-1);
    }

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n = 4;
    int grid = 1024;
    int grid_len = std::floor(std::log2(grid)) ; // what is the position of last 1, = how long i need to insert 0
    for (int steps = 0; steps*n < grid_len; ++steps)
    {
        std::cout << steps << std::endl;
        int preserve = grid % power(2,n*(steps+1) );
        grid = (grid - preserve) * 2;
        grid += preserve;
    }
    std::cout << grid << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code prints 71, which in binary is 1000111, so it works on example you provided.

Comment: Why have `power` return a `float`?

Comment: I copy pasted from some code of mine, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Why have a `power` at all if you're going to use it with 2 as the base? That's already built in as the << operator